# How to use curl GET instead of POST

Tags: php, curl

I'm tyring to use curl to print a return from a url.  The code I have so far looks like this:

```
<?php
    $street = $_GET['street'];
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $zip = $_GET['zip'];

    $url = 'http://eligibility.cert.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice';
    $query = 'eligibilityType=Property&requestString=<?xml version="1.0"?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd"><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1="'.$street.'" StreetAddress2="" StreetAddress3="" City="'.$city.'" State="'.$state.'" County="" Zip="'.$zip.'" Program="RBS"></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>';
    $url_final = $url.''.$url_query;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $return = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $return;

?>
```

the only obvious problem I know of it that the server being queried uses `GET` instead of `POST`.  Are there `GET` alternatives to this method?

Comment: That's a pretty long query string to be sending via GET. you may run into browser length limits and find that it's been decapitated or truncated.

Comment: If I run it in a browser, it works fine.  Would the rules for cURL be any different?

Comment: WHY would you downvote?  I'm asking if there's an alt to `POSTFIELDS` for `GET` method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

Curl uses GET by default. You were setting it to POST. You can override it if you ever need to with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);`

Comment: But what about the POSTFIELDS?  Do I just omit that and pass the query fields along with the URL?

Comment: Ya you'd fix this var to be `$url_final = $url.'?'.$url_query;` and then use that in your `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_final);`

Answer (score 4):

Use file_get_contents() function 
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Or 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => "http://yourlink.com",
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'));
```

Answer (score 1):

All these years and nobody's given the right answer; the way to build a query string is to use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) with an array. This automatically escapes everything and returns a simple string.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd"><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1="'.$street.'" StreetAddress2="" StreetAddress3="" City="'.$city.'" State="'.$state.'" County="" Zip="'.$zip.'" Program="RBS"></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>';
$data = [
    "eligibilityType" => "Property",
    "requestString" => $xml
];
$query = http_build_query($data);
$url .= "?$query";
```

Comment: Not sure that was the point of the question but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a question mark in the URL.
Should be like:

```
$query = '?eligibilityType=Property&...';
```

Also, that XML in your URL needs encoding, e.g. use the [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function in PHP.

Comment: Examples for cURL did not have a question mark.  Are you sure this is needed?