# curl with authentication header token - GET - PHP

Tags: php, curl, get

I have a token (string held in $token) and I need to retrieve a response (JSON) from an online service using curl.

The API requires GET.

```
$crl = curl_init();

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.$token;

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
$url = "ENDPOINT"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rest = curl_exec($crl);

curl_close($crl);

var_dump($rest);
```

Dumping $rest gives me:

```
 bool(false)
```

I based the above on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486988/how-to-use-curl-get-instead-of-post)

Comment: What does `echo curl_error($crl)` say?

Comment: Error: No URL set!

Comment: This is odd - the URL was set in $url

Comment: You have a real URL, not just the word `ENDPOINT`, right?

Comment: Yes, real URL that requires a token to be passed in the header in order to output a JSON response. I just wrote ENDPOINT in the post because the URL is not public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing variable names, ie. `$crl` and `$ch`, just clean that up and it should be fine or at least you should get something else besides false.

I would suggest you also [enable error_reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289) in your `php.ini`, you will easily find bugs like this in your code as you are developing.

In case it helps, this is what I am getting locally when running your code:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ch in /home/sebastianforsberg/env/test.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/sebastianforsberg/env/test.php on line 13
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ch in /home/sebastianforsberg/env/test.php on line 14
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/sebastianforsberg/env/test.php on line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ch in /home/sebastianforsberg/env/test.php on line 16
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/sebastianforsberg/env/test.php on line 16
bool(false)
```